# BlackBerry - How to put a background image behind a button?

Tags: java, blackberry

I need to make a screen like this:
[image]
The only thing I need to add to my code
is something to put the background image 
behind those buttons.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class PruebaScreen extends MainScreen{
    public PruebaScreen(){
         LabelField title = new LabelField("Screen Title");
         title.setPadding(40, 0, 20, 60);

         BitmapField btn1 = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn-1.png"));
         btn1.setPadding(2,0,3,0);

         BitmapField btn2 = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn-2.png"));
         btn2.setPadding(2,0,3,0);

         add(title);
         add(btn1);
         add(btn2);

    }
}
```

How should I do to put those two buttons
over the background image?. 
The image should not take all the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should

1. Create a manager (`VericalFieldManager`)
2. Set the desired background for the manager
3. Add the buttons to the manager
4. Add the manager to the screen

Here is a code snippet *that creates a solid color background*:

```
    LabelField title = new LabelField("Screen Title");
    title.setPadding(40, 0, 20, 60);

    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));
    vfm.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);

    ButtonField btn1 = new ButtonField("Option 1");
    btn1.setPadding(2, 0, 3, 0);

    ButtonField btn2 = new ButtonField("Option 2");
    btn2.setPadding(2, 0, 3, 0);

    add(title);
    vfm.add(btn1);
    vfm.add(btn2);
    add(vfm);
```

To make the background a bitmap, just replace

```
    vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));
```

with

```
    vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(YOUR BITMAP);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks MrVicenzo! since I'm using BlackBerry JRE 4.5.0,  VerticalFieldManager has not the method setBackground yet, so I had to override its paint() method to put the Bitmap =)